# how to select specific fields from the tables in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

This works but it gives all the fields of account table but only few are required.

```
$data = Loan::select('*')
    ->with([
        'member' => function ($query) {
            $query->addSelect('id', 'name');
        }, 
        'member.account'
    ])
    ->get();
```

This gives account: null

```
$data = Loan::select('*')
    ->with([
        'member' => function ($query) {
            $query->addSelect('id', 'name');
        }, 
        'member.account'=> function ($query) {
            $query->addSelect('id', 'account'); // if this line is commented, all the fields are returned but I just need few fields.
        }
    ])
    ->get();
```

Member model:

```
public function account()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Account::class); 
}
```

Account model:

```
public function member()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Member::class);
}
```

How can I get only the required fields of account table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the relationship and set it to give you specific columns like this.

on Member model

```
public function account()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Account::class)->select(['id', 'account']); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define required fields in `with`:

```
$data = Loan::select('*')
    ->with([
        'member' => function ($query) {
            $query->addSelect('id', 'name');
        }, 
        'member.account:id,number'
    ])
    ->get();
```

Comment: It gives following err: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ' id' in 'field list' (SQL: select ` id` from `accounts` where `accounts`.`member_id` in (1, 2) and `accounts`.`deleted_at` is null)

Comment: It seems you don't have id in account table. I wrote it as a sample. Please remove id and number and add whatever you want from account table.

Answer (score 0):

Your are close you just need to select the foreign key column that points to your account model , I guess it would be `account_id`, So you basically need to select 3 columns from your table which are `select(['id', 'name','account_id'])`

```
$data = Loan::with(['member' => function ($query) {
                   $query->select(['id', 'name','account_id'])
                         ->with(['account'=> function($query){
                              $query->select(['id','name']);
                          }]);
             }])
           ->get();
```

So if you have another nested relation account -> type and you need specific columns from type so you need to select the foreign key column from accounts models as

```
with(['account'=> function($query){
    $query->select(['id','name','type_id'])
          ->with(['type'=> function($query){
              $query->select(['id','name']);
           }]);
}]);
```